# Can I post executable binaries to into Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, security, ethics

I have updated the compiler, and I am struggling to get the binaries generated by the new compiler to work. I figure that besides describing the problem and the command lines involved, it will probably be useful to publish the final `.exe`s generated by the different compilers.

The problem is that people should be wary of executable files published by strangers on the internet, and some people might object the files on my post. And rightfully so: I may know there is no malware in my software, but this fact is hardly verifiable from the binaries only. On the other hand, people download prebuilt binaries from random strangers all the time.

So, what is the ethos in providing binary files on Stack Overflow? Can it be done or not?

Comment: If they’re short enough, you could include hexdumps of them in your posts.

Comment: If you need to upload binaries for people to repro the problem, then you haven't made a proper MCVE

Comment: Side note: "I may know there is no malware in my software" - there is not much correlation between "my code is not malware" and "binaries produced on my machine don't contain malware"...

Comment: Also, since you don't know what the problem is and can't get the executables to run in the way you expect them to, you clearly *don't even know* what is in those executables. :-) @Alexei

Answer (score 9):

No, you should not post binary files on Stack Overflow.

Not only is downloading something like that potentially dangerous, and would probably be avoided by the very experts whom you're hoping would answer your question, but Stack Overflow has a rule that questions must be self-contained. External links and off-site resources are okay as *supplemental* information, but all the information needed to solve the problem needs to be included directly as part of the question. This is why we don't allow links to code on GitHub or PasteBin or whatever, and it's the same reason why a download of a code file or executable file is not permissible.

All you need is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As you said: "describ[e] the problem and the command lines involved". You'll probably also want to include the exact source code that you're trying to compile.